Google recaptcha and third party cookie deprecation
currently running into questionable behaviour with recaptcha and third party cookies. I'm using the chrome://flags -> "Test Third Party Cookie Phaseout" option to test against our site to be sure nothing is broken when this blocking third party cookies feature is rolled out by google.
I keep getting errors like the image below from recaptcha, though it still seems to work.
With these errors i would think recaptcha breaks. Does anyone have ideas how cookies / recaptcha will function when Google rolls out this change. Should i be worried about these errors?


Short answer is: Try it and see if ReCaptcha still works on your site. If I know anything about how ReCaptcha works, it uses a cookie to re-authenticate humans who recently passed the test so users don't need to solve a captcha every single time. That's likely all that'll happen; users will still get captchas even after they've proven they're human.

Thanks, i haven't been getting bombarded with captcha to solve everytime which makes me think the cookies still work, though it doesn't give me peace of mind seeing these errors

While I haven't used captchas for some time, I imagine modern libraries use some sort of localStorage solution to get around the cookie restriction. It might depend on the implementation.

Disclaimer: I'm a reCAPTCHA team member.
reCAPTCHA continues to work without third-party cookies. We've long been preparing for this transition. See the following:
https://github.com/privacysandbox/privacy-sandbox-dev-support/blob/main/3pcd-readiness.md

That is great, but my OCD cannot cope with the massive amount of errors in my issues tab. Is there a way to get rid of that?

This third-pary cookies bottlenecks my web performance (light house score) too. You better remove it soon. Thanks.

So just to be clear cause I am somewhat confused over this, there will be nothing we need to change to our current implementation if using V2, V3 or enterprise recaptcha? Does this mean that the cookie being set by using the recaptcha service will be changed to some partioned cookie? _GRECAPTCHA  is the one I am referring to. thank you.
